# How to use getSupportActionBar in FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity, android-actionbaractivity

It says that `ActionBarActivity` is a subclass of `FragmentActivity`, but in my FragmentActivity I can't use `getSupportActionBar()`.
It works well when it extends ActionBarActivity, but I need exactly FragmentActivity for other stuff. I tried to use ActionBar v7, but it gives me NullPointerException also tried other things written here like:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar;
```

but none of them worked.

```
package com.example.campusinfo;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityTab extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff1699d1));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.title_activity);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_title);
        tv.setTextSize(35f);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/capriola.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(face);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to use ActionBarActivity if you want to have the actionbar. What's the reason why you can't extend it?

Comment: ActionBarActivity extends from FragmentActivity so why can't you use it?

Answer (score 4):

Just extend `ActionBarActivity`, and you can do all you want to do there

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActionBarActivity` and then use polymorphism for the other stuff you want to use `FragmentActivity` in.